# Jquery Show Menu when hover over <li>

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            lots of content 
        </li>
        <li>
            lots of content 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to show a menu with several custom links when the user hovers over each (li) item. Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

Any ideas would be much appreciated. I think i should be using Jquery somehow on the (li) elements of class calendar...

Comment: Look into `.show()` `.hide()` and `.toggle()`.

Comment: add a class do your list items.
After that bind it and call methos like mentioned above.

Comment: Before you rush to jQuery, you can probably find a pure CSS solution for this.

Comment: Yes, this can be purely CSS driven. No need for jQuery.

Comment: thanks guys but why did I get a -1 on my question.. i dont know what other details to write - i even went to the trouble of creating an image but the system wouldnt let me embed it myself bcs i dont have reputation 10..

Comment: this may help you http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/   and    http://css-plus.com/2010/06/how-to-make-a-jquery-drop-down-menu-with-a-css-fall-back/

Comment: Derek, so how can this be done just by using CSS ?

Comment: I'm sure the link @SwapneelKondgule posted will have lots of useful information for you.  The basics are to embed ULs in the LIs, set `.calendar li ul {display: none;}`, and then `.calendar li:hover ul {display: block;}`,  or something like that.

Comment: ok i think this is useful - thanks will try it out

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <img src="myimage.png" alt="lots of content" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            lots of content
        </li>
        <li>
            lots of content
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And use this CSS

```css
.calendar:hover ul, .calendar img {display: block;}
.calendar:hover img, .calendar ul {display: none;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/J99WS/